# How to know who has updated the table in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to know who has modified the table in the SQL server, But I couldn't find any authentic solution for this.

I tried function `fn_dblog`, but it is not allowing me due to some permission issue.

```
SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
```

**Error Message:**

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1 The SELECT permission was denied on
> the object 'fn_dblog', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

I refereed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jenss/want-to-know-what-happened-on-your-database-by-reading-the-transaction-log) article, but the link for the `fndblog2` function expired.

Basically, I want to get the list of users who have updated the given table, if it is modified in SSMS then user details and if it is modified by some .net application then .net application name.

**SSMS details:** Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU10) (KB5001090) - 15.0.4123.1 (X64)   Mar 22 2021 18:10:24   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

**Note:** Privelleged Permission can't be given to me due to securities issues. I am fine with writing a C# application. I am ok with writing C# appication if it is possible in C#.

Comment: Unless you have mechanism to log this, you likely *won't* know, and those mechanism are bespoke.

Comment: Perhaps you could build some logic around _truggers_ and _select ORIGINAL_LOGIN()_

Comment: You as a developer at the application level need to get that info from the connections and physically write it to the table at runtime.   This is why you often see  fields Like CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, CreateDate, UpdateDate on each record.

Comment: @SqlSurfer but what if someone directly update only one column of a table, I’m talking about those scenarios

Comment: Steve's comment about triggers may help you.  Also SQL has a built in concept called TEMPORAL TABLES - that may be relevant to what you are asking about.   I think Temporal tables may be what you are really driving at.

Comment: Using Developer edition for a production server instance?

Comment: It’s development server @SMor